# .htaccess redirect '/news' and '/news/../..'

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect '/news' and any URL that starts with '/news/...'. The idea is that a URL can either by /news (the whole list), /news/category (news list within 'category') etc. etc.

The longer URLs work, but '/news' bypasses my first redirect rule and hits the second. I'm not great with PHP or .htaccess so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
RewriteRule ^/?news([^\.]+)$ /news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /page.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?` to tell that the group is optional:

```
RewriteRule ^news(/[^.]*)?$ /page.php [L]
```

So the URLs `/news`, `/news/` and `/news/something` will match to this regular expression.

If you want to match to `/news` and `/news/something` only, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^news(/[^.]+)?$ /page.php [L]
```

Comment: This will still match /newssdfd, for example.

Comment: @ChrisWickham Yes. You only want `/news` or `/news/something`? You current rule do the same.

Comment: I want `/news` and `/news/something` to redirect to `news.php`. Everything else should go to `page.php`.

Comment: @ChrisWickham I've updated the answer to match to `/news`, `/news/` and `/news/something`.